# Casting to Sonos speakers from Android

Tags: android, sonos

In the app I'm working with we currently have Chromecast support, but we're interested in adding support for casting to Sonos speakers as well just as has been done in Play Music.

When listing available routes using the MediaRouter I see routes to all of our Sonos groups and Chromecasts, but while I can select the route to a Chromecast I can't do the same with a route to a Sonos speaker.

I tried to find more information about this on the [Sonos Labs](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/) site, but couldn't find anything related to Android.

Is there anything required from our app to support this? Is it possible to cast without integrating our service with the Sonos API, or would that be the first step in being able to cast from our own app?

Answer (score 1):

I presume you have written an app using the Cast SDK and are using the Cast APIs to perform the tasks that you want. The reason that you can work with Chromecast is that (1) Cast SDK introduces a MediaRouteProvider (MRP) for cast devices and (2) Cast SDK uses its APIs to cast using the provider. In case of Sonos, it needs to have a MRP and then you would need to call the APIs defined by that provider to manage sending commands, etc to your Sonos device. You can probably use pure MediaRouter commands/apis to communicate with the Sonos but I don't know much about Sonos to be able to say anything authoritative but it definitely doesn't work with the Cast SDK directly.

Comment: As far as I can see when debugging the Sonos routes have a MediaRouteProvider set, so maybe that could be a way of accessing these routes. It might not be enough if they require a custom permission, though, but without documentation from Sonos it's a bit difficult to know.